# image of vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

> Fix a real number $\alpha$ and define the function $F: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ as $F(z)=e^{i \alpha}  z .$ Find the image of vector field $X=-y \partial / \partial x+x \partial / \partial y$ under Differential of $F$.

we have :
$e^{i \alpha}=\cos \alpha+i \sin \alpha$ and $z=x+iy$ and now :

$F(z)=e^{i \alpha} z = (\cos \alpha+i \sin \alpha) (x+iy)=x\cos \alpha+x i \sin \alpha + yi\cos \alpha -y \sin \alpha$

Comment: Write $F$ as a function $\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$, like $F(x,y) = \left( x \cos \alpha - y \sin \alpha, \; x \sin \alpha + y \cos \alpha \right)$. Then find the Jacobian matrix of $F$ (i.e. the differential). Then multiply this matrix by the vector $(-y,x)^\top$.

Comment: @Nick . $J(F)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha\end{array}\right]$.why we must $
\text { multiply this matrix by the vector }(-y, x)^{\top}
$ ?

Comment: What way have you learned to apply a differential to a vector field?

Comment: Because $(-y,x)$ is the coordinate expression for the vector field $X$.

Comment: @Nick .so  image of vector field $X$ is : $J(F)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{l}-y \\ x\end{array}\right] = [-y \cos \alpha -x \sin \alpha ,-y \sin \alpha +x \cos \alpha]$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.